# Python Pandas Highlight single signs possible?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, highlight

I am really new to the whole python development and have a question. I would like to achieve the following result:

[image: ResultPicture]

However, in my research I only found the possibility to change the style for a whole cell.

I am doing a complete character by character comparison and would like to Colour the individual characters accordingly.

Maybe this can also be done with Python (my VBA script is very slow).

This is my python script till now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = "XXXXX"

data = pd.read_csv(path, names=["Dir1", "Dir2", "File1",    "File2",
                   "Diff",  "Line1",    "A",    "Line2",    "B"], sep="|")

line = 1

for ind in data.index:

    if data.A[ind] == data.B[ind]:
        var_ok = True
    else:
        #Work just with different Values
        var_ok = False
        var_length_A = len(str(data.A[ind]))
        var_length_B = len(str(data.B[ind]))
        #check length
        #A is longer
        if var_length_A > var_length_B:
            var_longer = var_length_A
        #Atos is longer
        elif var_length_A < var_length_B:
            var_longer = var_length_B
        #Same length
        else:
            var_longer = var_length_A

    for count in range(1,var_longer):
        #read every sign
        var_sign_A = mid(data.A[ind],count,1)
        var_sign_B = mid(data.B[ind],count,1)

        if var_sign_A != var_sign_B:
            #highlight this
        else:
            #Do nothing


    print([ind], "|\t", data.A[ind], "|\t", data.B[ind], "|\t",
          var_ok, "|\t", var_length_A, "|\t", var_length_B, "|\t", var_longer)
```

This is a part from my VBA script:

```
 'Wenn beide gefüllt sind
                Else
                    counter = 1
                    'Zeichen für Zeichen abgleich
                    For counter = counter To leng
                        If Mid(Cells(zeile, Spalte1), counter, 1) <> Mid(Cells(zeile, Spalte2), counter, 1) Then
                            
                            With Cells(zeile, Spalte2).Characters(start:=counter, Length:=1).Font
                                .Color = var2
                                .FontStyle = "Fett"
                            End With
                            With Cells(zeile, Spalte1).Characters(start:=counter, Length:=1).Font
                                .Color = var2
                                .FontStyle = "Fett"
                            End With
                        Else
                            With Cells(zeile, Spalte2).Characters(start:=counter, Length:=1).Font
                                .Color = var1
                                .FontStyle = "Standard"
                            End With
                            
                            With Cells(zeile, Spalte1).Characters(start:=counter, Length:=1).Font
                                .Color = var1
                                .FontStyle = "Standard"
                            End With
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
```

BR & thank you :)

Marcel

Comment: What part do you want to highlight exactly? You can use [this library](https://pypi.org/project/printj/) to color or bold the text or highlight it into any color.

Comment: I would like to visually highlight the differences between the two strings.